# Angular2 NgStyle not updating on click

Tags: angular, typescript

The component has a input from its parent and has an output event for this input object. The NgStyle takes a style object from the component for styling. The on click event changed the boolean but the style object is not updated accordingly, hence the color remain unchanged. I have to reassign a new object in order for the NgStyle to see the new boolean value. What am I doing wrong?

ProductItemComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {Product} from '../../model/product';

@Component({
selector: 'app-product-item',
templateUrl: './product-item.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./product-item.component.css']
})

export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public product!:Product;
  @Output() private updateStatus: EventEmitter<Product>;

  public statusTextStyle:object;
  public classStyle:object;

  constructor() {
    this.updateStatus = new EventEmitter<Product>();
  }


 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.statusTextStyle = {
       // if true color green, if false red
      "color" : this.product.getStatus() ? "var(--ok)" : "var(--danger)"
    }

 }

  onUpdateStatus(event){
    this.updateStatus.emit(this.product);

    // have to reassign a new object to change style
    this.statusTextStyle = {
      "color" : this.product.getStatus() ? "var(--ok)" : "var(--danger)"
    }

    console.log(this.statusTextStyle);
  }

}
```

Product-item.component.html:

```
<div class="productContainer">
  <div class="overlay">
      <div [ngStyle]="statusTextStyle">{{product.name}}</div>
      <hr>
      <div>Status: {{product.getStatus()}}</div>
      <div>Price: {{product.price}}</div>
      <br>
      <div>Code: {{product.code}}</div>
      <br>
      <div>Stock: {{product.quantity}}</div>
      <hr>
      <button (click)="onUpdateStatus($event)">UPDATE STATUS</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product as ProductModel} from '../../model/product';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-product-list',
   templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
 })

  export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Array<ProductModel>;

  constructor() { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.products = [
       new ProductModel('A','1',3,40),
       new ProductModel('B','2',4,50),
       new ProductModel('C','3',22,41),
       new ProductModel('E','4',342,433),
       new ProductModel('Z','5',33,477)
     ]
   }

   onUpdateStatus(product:ProductModel){

     product.setStatus(!product.getStatus());
     console.log(product.getStatus());

   }

 }
```

Parent html:

```
<div class="productList">
<div *ngFor="let product of products; let index as i;">

    <app-product-item [product]="product" (updateStatus)="onUpdateStatus($event)"></app-product-item>
    
</div>
```

Product Model:

```
  export class Product {

  private _status:boolean = false;

  constructor(public name:string,
              public code:string,
              public price:number,
              public quantity:number){}

  public getStatus():boolean{
      return this._status;
  }

  public setStatus(status:boolean):void{
      this._status = status;
    }
  }
```

if `this.statusTextStyle` is not reassigned with a new object (recall the getStatus()), the NgStyle use the style set in ngOnInit
[image]

**[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-t6sxio?file=src/app/product-item/product-item.component.ts)**

Comment: Can you provide your `ngStyle` code? I guess your problem is you should assign `this.statusTextStyle.color = this.product.getStatus() ? "var(--ok)" : "var(--danger)"`. And then you probably need to call `ChangeDetectorRef` (inject it) `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`. I don't recommend this approach because of performance, if you can provide more code maybe I can think something else. :)

Comment: why are you expecting `product.getStatus()` to return something different when nothing in this code ever seems to change anything in the product object? You also seem to be missing a `CommonModule` import based on that error message? also your `ngStyle` binding would be useful when asking a question about `ngStyle` usage.

Comment: @JorgeMussato I initialized the `this.statusTextStyle` to a new object in the `ngOnInit`. If I assign like `this.statusTextStyle.color` the error complaints: Property color does not exist on type 'object'.

Comment: @bryan60 I just picked up Angular recently and I followed the book `Angular Up and Running`. The `event emitter` in the component will trigger the event of this output from its parent if I understand it right. The value does changed as I showed in console.log

Comment: can u create a minimal stackblitz demo

Comment: @YogendraR added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CloudWave, you need initialize the output: `@Output() private updateStatus: EventEmitter<Product>=new EventEmitter<Product>();`

But if you check your code, see that you don't change the `statusTextStyle` in any place else ngOnInit. The ngOnInit happens only when the component is painted at first time (or if you has a component under a *ngFor and change the array of under a *ngIf also).

You can check that work if you uncomment the lines under your `//reassign object only works`.

Another way is make a getter

```
get statusTextStyle(){
    return {
      color: this.product.getStatus() ? "var(--ok)" : "var(--danger)"
    };
  }
```

Your [forked stackblitz using a getter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-itevvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-item%2Fproduct-item.component.ts)

NOTE: When you pass an object to an Input, you need'nt pass to the `@Output` the product, any change  in the object -in child or in parent- change the apaarence

**Update** well the note is not clear. I want to say that when you use as `@Input` with an object the object is the same always. You can change one property of the object anywhere -in parent or in child- So, we can do in child

```
  onUpdateStatus(event) {
    this.product.setStatus(!this.product.getStatus());
  }
```

We neend't change the "product" in parent and we needn't use an @Output.

Comment: I thought if I initialize the style in ngOnInit the style will keep changing after that. So the getter is used in the line `<div [ngStyle]="statusTextStyle">{{product.name}}</div>` ? What does it mean by `pass to the @Output the product` ?

Comment: the "ngOnInit" not create a relation between variables, get the actual variables and calculate the others. About the `@Input`, I updated the answer to clearly the note.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm doing an exercise actually. The books say in order for the child component to be truly reusable, the data object should be passed in by its parent component, that's why I use `@Output` decorator to provide encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Bro I want to add my piece of code here and its running perfectly maybe it will help you.

```
 Style1={
     fontSize: '3em',
     backgroundColor: this.CardData > 1 || this._ProductQuantity > 1 ? 'ivory' : "orange",
     color: this.CardData > 1 || this._ProductQuantity > 1 ? "green" : "red",
     'fa': true,
     'far fa-check-square': this.CardData > 1 || this._ProductQuantity > 1, 
     'far fa-times-circle': this.CardData < 1 || this._ProductQuantity < 1

   };
```

Instead of using the 'var(--ok)' I am using direct values of color.
If it helps you please tick my answer

Comment: ohhh. there might be some problem in the condition. Any other help?